# Remove app/webroot from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove app/webroot from the url in my CakePHP application using htaccess. We know it can be fixed just by pointing the vhost to the app/webroot folder, but for some reasons the developers over here prefer to fix this using htaccess.

Anyone who knows or this is possible?

Comment: Provide some examples of URIs you want to have and it would be good to know your efforts also.

Comment: I would like to change http://example.com/app/webroot/products/ to http://example.com/products/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup your various `.htaccess` like this:

**.htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT/app**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/webroot**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/webroot/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+app/webroot/([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```