# Remove "app" from url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using `cakephp 3`.

My .htaccess file is located at in DOCUMENT_ROOT.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I get

```
http://www.blogtest.com/app/first
```

I want:

```
http://www.blogtest.com/first
```

How can I remove "app" word form url ?

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. by using:  http://www.blogtest.com/first , it is working. But when I click on other link, it will goes on http://www.blogtest.com/app/second.
.htaccess file is in DOCUMENT_ROOT folder.

Comment: I have list of posts. They have url with '/app' word in it. And I want to remove that '/app' from url.
I have do as like your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20472350/4238284
But '/app' is still coming in url.

Comment: I have to be able to see your page to understand where `/app/` shows up in links. If you any URL that doesn't redirect me to some crappy `/?f` page then provide me those links.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava sir and ADmad sir for your help. By help of https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7386 by ADmad, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution by help of https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7386 by ADmad sir.

I changed wording in my `app.php` file.

In  'App' array, change `'base' => false` to `'base' => ''`.

Like

```
'App' => [
      // other elements
      'base' => '',
]
```